# Need help trying to make SESSION when a DIV is click (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, paypal

I'm trying to make an session when the div is click but I can't seem to get it to work and i'm trying to make a reservation form then make paypal as its payment been trying other methods to use other of paypal payment but this one is the only that seems working but it will only saved its data from the paypal user information

Here is my PHP file

```
<?php
// Redirect to the home page if id parameter not found in URL
if(empty($_GET['id'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

// Include and initialize database class
include 'DB.class.php';
$db = new DB;

// Include and initialize paypal class
include 'PaypalExpress.class.php';
$paypal = new PaypalExpress;

// Get product ID from URL
$productID = $_GET['id'];

// Get product details
$conditions = array(
    'where' => array('id' => $productID),
    'return_type' => 'single'
);
$productData = $db->getRows('products', $conditions);

// Redirect to the home page if product not found
if(empty($productData)){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label>Full Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
    <label>Contact Number</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="contactno"><br>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <label>Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    <label>Check In</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="datein"><br>
    <label>Check Out</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="dateout"><br>
    <label>Room Type</label><br>
    <select name="roomtype">
        <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
        <option value="Deluxe">Deluxe</option>
    </select><br>
    <!-- Product details -->
    <p>Name: <?php echo $productData['name']; ?></p>
    <p>Price: <?php echo $productData['price']; ?></p>

    <!-- Checkout button -->
    <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</form>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
JavaScript code to render PayPal checkout button
and execute payment
-->
<script>
paypal.Button.render({
    // Configure environment
    env: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalEnv; ?>',
    client: {
        sandbox: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>',
        production: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>'
    },
    // Customize button (optional)
    locale: 'en_US',
    style: {
        size: 'small',
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'pill',
    },
    // Set up a payment
    payment: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [{
                amount: {
                    total: '<?php echo $productData['price']; ?>',
                    currency: 'PHP'
                }
            }]
      });
    },
    // Execute the payment
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
        .then(function () {
            // Show a confirmation message to the buyer
            //window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');

            // Redirect to the payment process page
            window.location = "process.php?paymentID="+data.paymentID+"&token="+data.paymentToken+"&payerID="+data.payerID+"&pid=<?php echo $productData['id']; ?>";
        });
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Comment: Which div? Where are you trying to make a session? What is supposed to happen when the form is posted? There is no post processing in this example.

Comment: You have better luck getting your answers if you ask only one question at a time and provide a [mcve] that includes only the code relevant to the scope of that individual question.